# How to find Object ID in PHP?

Tags: php, object

I'm using PHP 5.2. I'd like to find a way to output a unique id for every object, so it's easy when looking over logs to see which objects are the same.

In Ruby, I'd just say object.object_id to get Ruby's internal identifier for the object. There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do this in PHP.

Is there is a built-in way of doing this? If there isn't, can you offer any other suggestions?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use [`spl_object_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php) for that.

It returns an unique identifier for each object instance, and not the name of the class, so it seems more suitable for you.

**Edit:**

For PHP < 5.2.x users, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19250740/179104).

Comment: If the objects are equal i.e. differing only by identity the object hashes produces by `spl_object_hash()` can appear very similar. I just tried it and I got this:

  a: 00000000462ff471000000005e39f75b
  b: 00000000462ff46c000000005e39f75b

Those are different but you have to look carefully.

Comment: Also, note the comment of planetbeing on the reference page about the hashes possibly being the same when the reference is destroyed.

Comment: @Ollie Saunders, To correct this, you can take the hash (e.g. SHA1) of the `sql_object_hash()`.  However, there *could* be collisions, but I don't think that's something to worry about in this case.

Comment: spl_object_hash  is only for PHP 5 >= 5.2.0.
Whar about PHP 5.1.x?

Comment: Regarding the uniqid() edit of this post: my answer on this question got deleted by a mod and voted down -2 as not relevant (in a comment) because I suggested using uniqid(). I still think this is the best way to ensure a unique id, even with php 5.3 because the hash can be reused after destruction.

Comment: I also think that it's better to achieve it manually (with uniqid() or another randomly generated identifier). Good to avoid the collision problem @koen pointed in a previous comment.

Comment: "...so it's easy when looking over logs to see which objects are the same." Note: When an object is destroyed, its hash may be reused for other objects. (from above, official php doc)

Comment: Please correct the answer, as I just now expierienced first hand that the identifier is not unique over all object instances created but only over all currently undestroyed objects. See mindplay.dk answer

Comment: As a side note, if the older object is garbage (or weakly reachable), the identifier may repeat. No matter the object count ID or the hash, it might still be the same. Refer to this test.
https://gist.github.com/SOF3/f472f849c57ade8ae5a8dc306ceba29b

Answer (score 17):

There is currently no way to do this in PHP, as of version 5.3.6.

spl_object_hash() does not do what you want - because it recycles the identifiers when objects get deleted, this will lead to errors in (for example) an object-relational mapper trying to keep track of objects in a session.

The description at the top of the documentation page ("This function returns a unique identifier for the object. This id can be used as a hash key for storing objects or for identifying an object.") is wrong - the truth is revealed in the note on that page: "When an object is destroyed, its hash may be reused for other objects", or in other words, the function does *not* always return a unique identifier, and can *not* always be used for storing or identifying objects.

The technique demonstrated in [this comment](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php#94060) may work in some cases, but it not reliable and will not work consistently either, since attempting to access an undefined property will invoke the __get() and __set() magic methods, the results of which are unpredictable.

In conclusion, the short answer to your question (unfortunately) is "no" - there is no such method in PHP, and there is no way to write a method like this that will work consistently for any object.

If you would like to see this feature added to PHP, please vote and/or comment here:

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52657

Comment: The alternative technique will work as long as the given object does not implement `__get`, `__set` and `__isset` magic methods. You're right that (for example) an object relational mapper may use these ones, to map undefined properties to table columns. Weird things can happen at this point when the ORM tries to handle the `__oid__` property.

Comment: I believe you're just repeating what I already said about the magic methods?

And most modern ORMs use ClassReflection::getProperties() so they won't see the __oid__ property.

If your ORM really doesn't use _any_ kind of property filtering, and just blindly persists all properties, I would argue extremely poor design anyway - most ORMs use a mapping configuration, conventions, embedded meta-data or table-reflection, or combinations of those...

Comment: No, I was just explaining better what you said about magic methods, which was not 100% correct. You missed `__isset` :)

Answer (score 9):

## ⚠️ PHP 7.2.0 introduces [spl_object_id()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-id.php)!

```php
$test = (object)[];
var_dump(spl_object_id($test)); # int(1)
```

**Caveat emptor(?)**:

> When an object is destroyed, its id may be reused for other objects.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old topic, but i think i've found a solution.

The trick is in storing reference to each object in array with assigned key.
You can then get object id by searching through that array and returning found key.

```
<?php

class objectMarker
{
    private $storage;

    function add($object) {
        $this->storage[] = $object;
    }

    function getId($object) {
        foreach ($this->storage as $id => $item) {
            if ($item === $object) {
                return $id;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

$marker = new objectMarker;

$t1 = new stdClass;
$t2 = new stdClass;

$marker->add($t1);
$marker->add($t2);

echo $marker->getId($t1) . "\n";
echo $marker->getId($t2) . "\n";

unset($t1);

$t1 = new stdClass;
$marker->add($t1);

echo $marker->getId($t1) . "\n";

$t2->x = 1;
echo $marker->getId($t2) . "\n";

/* output:
0
1
2
1
*/
```