# What is #<some-number> next to object(someClass) in var_dump of an object? I have an inference. Am I right?

Tags: php, php-internals

This is the code & its output I used to draw the inference below:

```
 class a {
    public $var1;
    public $var2;
    }

 $obj0 = new a;
 var_dump($obj0);

 class b {
    public $var1;
    public $var2;
    public $var3;
    }

 $obj1 = new b;
 var_dump($obj1);

 $obj2 = new stdClass;
 var_dump($obj2);

 $obj3 = new stdClass;
 var_dump($obj3); 

 $obj4 = new stdClass;
 var_dump($obj4);

 $obj5 = new stdClass;
 var_dump($obj5);

 var_dump(new stdClass); 

 $obj6 = new stdClass;
 var_dump($obj6);
```

The output:

```
object(a)#1 (2) {
  ["var1"]=> NULL
  ["var2"]=> NULL
}
object(b)#2 (3) {
  ["var1"]=> NULL
  ["var2"]=> NULL
  ["var3"]=> NULL
}
object(stdClass)#3 (0) {

}
object(stdClass)#4 (0) {

}
object(stdClass)#5 (0) {

}
object(stdClass)#6 (0) {

}
object(stdClass)#7 (0) {

}
object(stdClass)#7 (0) {

}
```

The `#<some-number>` next to the line `object(someClass)` in `var_dump` of an object is actually `#<count>`. Where,

> count is the number of *objects* / *zval's for objects* irrespective of which class it belongs to that has been created till now. Which keeps getting incrementing for every object created & gets decremented by 1 when a refcount of a zval reaches zero i.e. Garbage Collection.

Am I right?

Comment: Do you remember the [object identifier that PHP has](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) from one of your previous question about garbage collection/cow?

Comment: @hakre Yes I do remember. Pardon for the delayed reply. Going through the answers now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That number is `Z_OBJ_HANDLE_PP(struc)` where `struc` is a `zval` which leads to `Z_OBJVAL(zval).handle` which leads to `(zval).value.obj`.

See as well http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php

In short I would say it's the [object identifier](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) written in decimal form ([ref](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/var.c#87)):

```
php_printf("%sobject(%s)#%d (%d) {\n", COMMON, class_name, Z_OBJ_HANDLE_PP(struc), myht ? zend_hash_num_elements(myht) : 0);
```

And not the count of objects ever created.

Comment: yup the definition lead to `(zval).value.obj`.  `Value` is a member of `struct _zval_struct` of the type `zvalue_value` and `obj` is a member of `_zvalue_value` ( `zvalue_value` )  of the type `zend_object_value` Thanks!

Comment: from ([ref](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/Zend/zend_types.h)):  zend_object_value:  _zend_object_value (`zend_object_value` ) which has `zend_object_handle handle;` & `zend_object_handlers *handlers;` whose typedefs are `typedef unsigned int zend_object_handle;`
`typedef struct _zend_object_handlers zend_object_handlers;` respectively. Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

No, it's an internal reference to the object instance, if you did

```
var_dump($obj1);
```

again, it would still be id #2

**EDIT**

In the case of your

```
var_dump(new stdClass);
```

PHP is creating a new instance of stdClass and dumping it using var_dump, giving you instance #7. However, because this instance is transient (you're not assigning it to any variable) it's being destroyed again immediately afterwards, so object id #7 is available again for allocation to the next object that you create with

```
$obj6 = new stdClass;
```