# Resource type in PHP

Tags: php, resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is #<some-number> next to object(someClass)  in var_dump of an object? I have an inference. Am I right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787893/what-is-some-number-next-to-objectsomeclass-in-var-dump-of-an-object-i-ha)

I understand that some function return resource id e.g. #123 in PHP e.g. `mysql_query`.

My question is why does object has that number and what is it used for? Is it a resource id too

```
$obj = new MyClassName();
var_dump($obj);

output: object(MyClassName)#324 (0)
```

What is the meaning of #324 in this context?

Comment: The same as `12344321` in `Object@12344321` in Java, I believe. Not even a little interesting (except for hashing purposes) to the application.

Answer (score 1):

Id with reference is use to track uniqueness of the resource, PHP create unique resource every time when new resource is generated. When your resource get free using unset() function that particular id get destroy so don't use this id for referencing as it will generate new id every time.