# Issue with the output objects

Tags: php

In one script, i use `var_dump()` to output the objects:

```
foreach ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS'][$this->extKey.'/'.$this->scriptRelPath] as $classRef) {
                $hookObj = t3lib_div::getUserObj($classRef);
                var_dump($hookObj);
```

The result is:

```
object(tx_job_dagoupost)#73 (3) { ["extKey"]=> string(3) "job" ["prefixId"]=> string(10) "tx_job_pi1" ["scriptRelPath"]=> string(32) "hooks/class.tx_job_dagoupost.php" } 
object(tx_christianvolunteer_dagoupost)#79 (2) { ["extKey"]=> string(19) "christian_volunteer" ["scriptRelPath"]=> string(47) "hooks/class.tx_christianvolunteer_dagoupost.php" } 
object(tx_watermark_dagoupost)#73 (2) { ["extKey"]=> string(9) "watermark" ["scriptRelPath"]=> string(38) "hooks/class.tx_watermark_dagoupost.php" }
```

Question:

1. what does `#73` and `#79` mean?
2. `object(tx_job_dagoupost)#73` and `object(tx_watermark_dagoupost)#73` are different objects, but they have same id `#73`, why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787893/what-is-some-number-next-to-objectsomeclass-in-var-dump-of-an-object-i-ha

Comment: [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) check this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787893/what-is-some-number-next-to-objectsomeclass-in-var-dump-of-an-object-i-ha) sign # is PHP internal identifier for object.
2. Same identifiers for different objects means that your first object (tx_job_dagoupost) was transient (not assigned to any variable or variable was unset) and PHP used same identifier for next object.