# Get the 'name' of object(stdClass) from array

Tags: php, arrays, json, stdclass

From an API I receive an array like this:

```
$data=array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#24 (2) {
        ["key1"]=> string(5) "val1"
        ["key2"]=> string(5) "val2"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#25 (2) {
        ["key1"]=> string(5) "val3"
        ["key2"]=> string(5) "val4"
      }
}
```

It's no problem to get the keys or values. But is there a way to get the "name" of the object e.g. "**#24**" or "**#25**"?

Please excuse me if my question is not properly formulated....

Comment: That isn't a name, it's an internal resource reference.... why do you actually need it? What do you want to use it for?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8787893/3933332

Comment: @Rizier123 : Thanks!