# how to get key from object(stdClass)[key]?

Tags: php, oop

I want to create new array base on object with structure like this :

```
object(stdClass)[33]
  public 'IKSindividuList' => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[27] // <---- i need to get the 27
          public 'indikator' => string 'nik' (length=3)
          public 'value' => string '123654789' (length=9)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[28]
          public 'indikator' => string 'name' (length=4)
          public 'value' => string 'afdikage' (length=8)
```

and the new array that i want to create, more or less should look like this :

```
array(size=6)
27 => // and put the 27 as index number
   array(size=1)
     'nik' => '123654789'
28 => 
   array(size=1)
     'name' => 'afdikage'
```

I don't have any idea what is that number and how to get it. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is #<some-number> next to object(someClass) in var\_dump of an object? I have an inference. Am I right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787893/what-is-some-number-next-to-objectsomeclass-in-var-dump-of-an-object-i-hav)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. If you use XDebug you get this in the brackets, if you don't it will be after the hash like this `object(stdClass)#1`
2. This is object identifier, which you should not rely or care in real life. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php
3. You can get the object ID using [`spl_object_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-id.php), but that seems like a bad idea. Consider if the object gets destroyed that ID might get reused and your will not have any real meaning.

You can also take a look at a similar SO question [What is # next to object(someClass) in var_dump of an object? I have an inference. Am I right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787893/what-is-some-number-next-to-objectsomeclass-in-var-dump-of-an-object-i-hav)